# Mysql select oldest record for each user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a list in PHP of the oldest entries for each user in the database.

```
SELECT *, 
MIN(`entries`.`entry_date`) 
AS entry_date 
FROM (`entries`) 
JOIN `user_profiles` 
ON `user_profiles`.`user_id` = `entries`.`user_id` 
WHERE `status` = 1 
GROUP BY `entries`.`user_id`
```

I'm using the query to retrieve from the `entries` table the oldest dated entry using `MIN()`and joining with table `user_profiles` for other data. The query should select the oldest entry for each user. It seems to work but it retrieves the wrong `entry_date` field on some entries when I echo them. Please help, I can't spot what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to obtain the `(user_id, entry_date)` pairs for each user, then join that with a query that selects the records of interest:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   entries
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT   user_id, MIN(entry_date) AS entry_date
    FROM     entries
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS tmin
  JOIN user_profiles USING (user_id)
WHERE  status = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the query and got `Duplicate column name 'entry_date'` then I changed `AS another_name` but get the same result with incorrect oldest entries

Comment: @CyberJunkie: Does the `user_profiles` table also contain a column named `entry_date`?  Also I noticed a typo in my original answer (now corrected): I was referencing a table named `events` instead of `entries` - had you already caught that?

Comment: no but it contains other columns that I need. The query successfully retrieves the oldest `entry_date` for each user using `MIN()` but the other rows don't correspond with it when I echo in php

Comment: @CyberJunkie: How can the query "successfully retrieve" anything if it's throwing that `Duplicate column` error?  Confused.

Comment: sorry I fixed the duplicate error by renaming `MIN(entires.entry_date)` but get the initial result. correct oldest entry dates but wrong entry for each one

Comment: @CyberJunkie: Renaming the column will break the `NATURAL JOIN`, so it's no surprise that doesn't work.  Can't understand why my query is producing that `Duplicate column` error.  Are you using **exactly** what I put above?

Comment: I am using Codeigniter for the query and it was causing the error. I fixed the problem and so far it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried approaching the problem from the user_profiles table instead of the entries table? If a user has no entries, they will not appear in the above query.

This may help, but I'm not sure if it's the full solution:

```
SELECT *, MIN(entries.entry_date) as entry_date
FROM user_profiles LEFT JOIN entries USING (user_id)
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY user_profiles.user_id
```

Also, you're renaming the MIN(entires.entry_date) as entry_date... but you already have a column named entry_date. Try renaming the derived columns to something unique like "min_entry_date"?

Comment: Thank you! I tried your query but get same results.. maybe its a php issue